# The best way to implement "I saw it at least once" in Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I need to implement something like "that particular value was emitted by publisher at least once in the past". So basically true/false.
As an example to answer if zero was ever send here:

```
let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
...
for _ in 1...3 {
    publisher.send(Int.random(in: 0...2))
}
```

I came up only with the following options and both feels unnatural somehow:

```
//Option #1 Using scan
let hadZero = publisher
    .scan(false) { $0 || $1 == 0 }

//Option #2 Merging with CurrentValueSubject
let hadZero = Publishers.Merge(
    CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false),
    publisher.contains { $0 == 0 }
)
```

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `contains` operator, which emits `true` immediately when the value sought is emitted by its upstream or emits `false` when the upstream completes without having emitted the sought value.

```
let hadZero = publisher.contains(0)
```

Comment: I actually used it in Merge option. 
`when the upstream completes` That's the problem. What I need is a sort of a replacement for a boolean flag, means I can always "consult" it about current value, for example by zipping or combining with another publisher